# Is there a way to NOT refresh the Page after Updating the data? Laravel 8 and Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-8

How can I not refresh or reload the page after updating the data?
I am using Modal to edit the data but the problem is the page still refresh after saving it, is there another way around to fix this concern?

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" @click="edit(item)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Employee Edit</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="formEdit.name">
                    </div>
                  ......
```

Script: (`edit` is used to show the data and `update` is used to update the data)

```
edit(item){
    const vm = this;
    vm.formEdit.name = item.name;
    vm.formEdit.address = item.address;
    vm.formEdit.position = item.position;
    this.selectedId = item.id;
    $('#editModal').modal('show');

},
update(){
    const vm = this;
    axios.put(`/employees/${vm.selectedId}`, this.formEdit)
    .then(function (response){
      alert('Employee Updated')
      location.reload();
    })
    .catch(function (error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

This is for Laravel 8 and Vue

employees component:

```
props: ['employee'],
data() {
    return {
        employeeList: this.employee,
        form:{
            name: null,
            address: null,
            position: null
        },
        formEdit:{
            name: null,
            address: null,
            position: null
        },
        selectedId: null
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, in fact, that's the main purpose of reactive frameworks. Once you successfully do the put request you should propagate the `response.data` to your main component. Please share the component where you want to show the employees data.

Comment: @Luciano Hello, kindly see my updated code above. Thank you, sir

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Once an employee is updated, where do you want to show the updated data? Do you have a table? a show component?

Comment: @Luciano yes, I have table and this is where I am pushing it `vm.employeeList.push(response.data.data)` .. you can say that `employeeList` is the table list to display my data

Answer (score 3):

Please next time add all relevant code to let us know what are you trying to achieve.

First of all, please note that data provided from `props` should not be mutated because of an anti-pattern. Said that you have to create a deep copy within your component in order to change its content.

Assuming that you are working in just 1 component, where you have your table listing all employees, you can do something like this.

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr v-for="item in employeeList" :key="item.id">
                <td>name: {{ item.name }}</td>
                <td>address : {{ item.address  }}</td>
                <td>position : {{ item.position  }}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-warning" @click="edit(item)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Employee Edit</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="form.name">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button class="btn btn-success" @click="update()">Save</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        employee: Array
    },

    data: () => ({
        employeeList: [],
        form: {}
    }),

    mounted () {
        // Since changing a props is anti-pattern, we use a local data which can be manipulated
        this.employeeList = [...this.employee]
    },

    methods: {
      edit(item){
          // Assign the clicked item to form data
          this.form = item
          $('#editModal').modal('show')
      },

      update(){
          axios.put(`/employees/${this.form.id}`, this.form)
            .then(function (response){
                alert('Employee Updated') 
                // Find the employee index in employeeList array
                const updatedEmployee = response.data
                const index = this.employeeList.findIndex(x => x.id === updatedEmployee.id)
                // If employee is found, then proceed to update the array object by using ES6 spread operator
                if (index !== -1) {
                    this.employeeList = [...this.employeeList.slice(0, index), { ...updatedEmployee}, ...this.employeeList.slice(index + 1)]
                }             
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                console.log(error)
            })
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Code is self-explanatory, but just in case I will clarify a little bit:

1. Because we can not mutate the props `employee`, we copy the array to local data by using the ES6 spread operator in `mounted()` hook.
2. When you click the button to edit an employee, you assign the `item` to the `form` data. Now you have the `form` with all employee data to be shown/changed anywhere.
3. Once success API response, since you are updating, you look for the array object and replace the whole array to avoid reactivity issues. In case you are adding a new one, you just can push it by doing `this.employeeList.push(updatedEmployee)`

EDIT: please note that the above code is a suggestion about how to work with a clean code.
Anyway, right to your question, you can update your array in your axios response by doing

```
            .then(function (response){
                alert('Employee Updated') 
                // Find the employee index in employeeList array
                const updatedEmployee = response.data
                const index = this.employeeList.findIndex(x => x.id === updatedEmployee.id)
                // If employee is found, then proceed to update the array object by using ES6 spread operator
                if (index !== -1) {
                    this.employeeList = [...this.employeeList.slice(0, index), { ...updatedEmployee}, ...this.employeeList.slice(index + 1)]
                }             
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                console.log(error)
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

during update remove

```
location.reload();
```

and add the below code

```
$('#editModal').modal('hide');
```

To display data follow the procedure, update data receive from response:

```
updateStudent(){
            axios.put('update_student',{
                id:this.id,
                name:this.editname,
                email:this.editemail,
                phone:this.editphone,
            })
             .then(response=>console.log(response));
             axios.get('all_students')
            .then(response => {
                this.data = response.data;
            });
        },
```

You can display the updated data like the below code:

```
<tr v-for="row in data"> 
  <th scope="row">1</th> 
  <td>{{ row.name }}</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: I've tried this already but I still need to refresh the page to get the updated data. It only closes the modal

Comment: i have added another code please check this. If you still have problem you can tell me.

Comment: It does not update still to my data, but can I ask if do you know how can I do this into update? `vm.employeeList.push(response.data.data)` because this data is on my submit part and this line of code gives my the result without refreshing the page. Is there a way to make this one to the update?

Comment: You need to get the response like this:  this.data = response.data; 

.then(response=>console.log(response));
             axios.get('all_students')
            .then(response => {
                this.data = response.data;
            });

and then loop it like:

<tr v-for="row in data">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an item in data to assign the value we get from props. Next, let's assign props data to the created element.
The page refresh issue will be resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).